"Firmware Update Available" notification pops up but nothing happens when I click on it
I just got a brand new HP laptop and installed Ubuntu 23.10 yesterday. Today I'm getting a pop up notification that says "Firmware Update Available", and more about which versions are available. When I click on it it just disappears. After about an hour it displays again. Is this normal?

On the command line run sudo fwupdmgr update and let it finish.  Then run a cold reboot - full shutdown and then start up from a cold boot setup

I did the update manually. I clicked on the Apps icon and found Firmware Updater. I opened that and then selected the UEFI dbx option in the left column. Once that came up there was an option to update the firmware. I clicked on that and then selected restart.
